# Spinner down arrow disappears below view background

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

[image: Down arrow hidden]

The following views are inside a ConstraintLayout:

```
<View android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="0dp"
     android:background="@color/white"
     app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/pickup_date"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/pickup_date" />

<Spinner android:id="@+id/pickup_date"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />
```

As you can see, it is hiding the down arrow on the spinner.

But when is set the visibility of the `View` to be `gone` it looks like this -

[image: Down arrow showing]

How do I achieve a white background using the view

Answer (score 1):

Remove attribute `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/pickup_date"` from `View`.

**Try this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Select a pickup date"
        android:textColor="#000"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/pickup_date"
        android:layout_width="336dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pickup_date"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Your view `constrain` was not proper.

`View` attributes `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/pickup_date"` and `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/pickup_date"`, will place `View` over center position of `Spinner`.

See [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html) for details.

To show `spinner` over `View`, do below changes:

**1.** Add attribute `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"` to `View`.

**2.** Add attribute `app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/view"` to `spinner`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Select a pickup date"
        android:textColor="#000"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/view"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/pickup_date"
        android:layout_width="352dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/view"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="33dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Hope this will help~

Comment: This is not what I want, I want the white background/View behind the spinner. Not below

Comment: When I meant above, I meant in a depth point of view. Not up and down

Comment: did you applied my updated answer? It will show spinner over  view. Your view constrain was not proper.

Comment: May i know the reason of down-voting?

Comment: Yep, 2 reasons, I explicitly mentioned in the above comments that I was talking about depth and not the kind of arrangement you've done. Also for people who are seeking the answer, they shouldn't go down this path and this is a way to assure it

Comment: I have already explained the reason in my updated answer. Please update your question first for others. `How do I achieve a white background using the view' dose not seems to be perfect for your ultimate requirements.

Comment: Lol, you are the first person here who is blaming the question for an incorrect answer.

Comment: what does it mean "How do I achieve a white background using the view"?

Comment: Did you found your problem?

Comment: Yea I found my problem, just not the answer and reason to the solution

Comment: May i know the solution? I think it will help me to understand the meaning of depth point of view.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I've said, please re-read it

Comment: i am talking about the problem that you found.

Comment: So am I, and if you want  to continue the chat please start a new chat session, let's keep it outside this :)